# Cannot install application after certain minutes

Tags: windows-7, installation

After 15 minutes* have passed, my laptop won't run any `.exe` to install applications. This is what shows up:

[image]

If I restart my laptop, it works fine (it gets installed)... until another 15 minutes* passed, then the exactly same error appears. I've tried changing the UAC permission but to no avail. This problems also happens to certain already-installed-softwares; e.g., I can't run any Source-based games (Left 4 Dead 2, Counter Strike, etc) after 15 minutes have passed.

Any help? :/

---

- fifteen minutes is just my estimation. I'm not sure how long it is actually.

Comment: Have you done a virus search? Are you running as admin (not that it should matter). And a Malware search. Does it occur when logged in with other accounts? Do application such as Calculator work after 15 minutes, and do the programs which don't work require internet access?

Comment: Get ccleaner and just remove all temporary useless files. After that go to run (Win+R) and type temp and then delete everything and then typr %temp% in run and do the same(some files might not get deleted so don't worry). Try installing after a reboot.

Comment: Most applications (.exe files) are fine. Default apps from Windows and many apps are working fine. But a few apps, like those I mentioned above, won't run after 15 minutes (those do not require internet access). I'm always running as admin, tried another account, also I ran MalwareBytes... still the same. I haven't tried CCleaner though. This isn't a big deal actually, but incredibly annoying because I have to restart just to install some programs or to play a number of games. :/

Answer (score 0):

i'm not really sure but do following steps :
1. turn off any startup application (access via msconfig)
2. restart your PC
3. try to run some app or games and if after 15 minutes (estimated) still won't work..
4. you have to turn off anti-virus to run apps or games.

Comment: I've tried turning off firewall and anti-virus, but it's still the same...

Comment: mmm..,.,i think your HDD have virus (especially on .exe files)

Comment: try to reinstall Windows (use new one from another source)
install Avast professional
use boot scan
during the scan you have to delete all .exe that suspected as virus
why? we have to reduce the risk of your new OS will be infected by virus.

Comment: I doubt if it's virus though, because it's working fine with many other applications. It's just the installer files and a number of games that won't run, so I have to restart the computer. I'm afraid to use Avast; last time I used Avast (3-4 years ago) it wiped out system files on my old laptop so I have to bought a new one. I'm using MSE and MalwareBytes and they didn't find anything...

Comment: that's exactly my problem a couple years ago. I decided to clean install OS and deleted all infected files (scan by avast), probably it's hard desicion because you have to delete all installer.
actually that's virus was popular 2 years ago, but i forgot :D
quit annoying

Comment: my problem is not in the installer, because newly-downloaded installers still won't install. I highly doubt this is a virus. I suspect it's related to user access control or something.